# hcitool scan says No such device

Tags: raspbian, hardware, bluetooth, pi-3, raspi-config

Using Raspberry Pi 3, Linux test 4.4.9-v7+ #884 SMP Fri May 6 17:28:59 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
root@raspberry:/home/user# hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
```

What can be the issue here?

I have updated to latest

```
#sudo rpi-update
```

I have installed rpi-bluetooth

```
#sudo apt-get install rpi-bluetooth
```

This can be seen from dmesg:

```
root@raspberry:/home/user# dmesg | grep Blue
[   43.442353] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   43.442453] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   43.442477] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   43.442494] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   43.442528] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   73.520196] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   73.520215] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   73.520238] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

**EDIT:**

This might also be interesting, why is not Bluetooth here?:

```
root@raspberry:/home/user# rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**EDIT 2:**
I have tried to reinstall pi-bluetooth

```
user@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt-get purge bluez-firmware
[sudo] password for user: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-firmware* pi-bluetooth*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 240 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 47373 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pi-bluetooth (0.1.0) ...
Purging configuration files for pi-bluetooth (0.1.0) ...
Removing bluez-firmware (1.2-3+rpi1) ...

user@raspberry:~ $ sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bluez-firmware
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bluez-firmware pi-bluetooth
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/92.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 240 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package bluez-firmware.
(Reading database ... 47354 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bluez-firmware_1.2-3+rpi1_all.deb ...
Unpacking bluez-firmware (1.2-3+rpi1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pi-bluetooth.
Preparing to unpack .../pi-bluetooth_0.1.0_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking pi-bluetooth (0.1.0) ...
Setting up bluez-firmware (1.2-3+rpi1) ...
Setting up pi-bluetooth (0.1.0) ...
Job for hciuart.service failed. See 'systemctl status hciuart.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

I suspect that the last error has something to do with it:
**Job for hciuart.service failed. See 'systemctl status hciuart.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.**

```
user@raspberry:~ $ sudo journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Sun 2016-05-08 19:48:33 CEST, end at Sun 2016-05-08 19:58:07 CEST. --
May 08 19:52:46 raspberry systemd[1]: Failed to start Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
-- Subject: Unit hciuart.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit hciuart.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 08 19:52:46 raspberry systemd[1]: Unit hciuart.service entered failed state.
May 08 19:52:46 raspberry hciattach[1279]: Can't initialize device: Success
May 08 19:52:46 raspberry hciattach[1279]: bcm43xx_init


user@raspberry:~ $ systemctl status hciuart.service
● hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-05-08 19:52:46 CEST; 6min ago
  Process: 1279 ExecStart=/usr/bin/hciattach /dev/ttyAMA0 bcm43xx 921600 noflow - (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
user@raspberry:~ $
```

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference but what if you call hcitool with sudo?

Comment: No difference, I have already runned sudo bash so I am in a root shell

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I wonder how you solved it

Comment: I see the same issue on my Pi 3 Model B V1.2, and I found that putting the exact same SD card in my Pi 3 B+ worked without issue. If you have another Pi 3, maybe try that out and see if it works? Others have reported this issue in the past, but software fixes worked for them, and keep failing for me. I can't attach to the BT module. https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/1314#issuecomment-190788662, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44554255/bcm43xx-init-initialization-timed-out-with-buildroot-raspberry-pi-3-hciattach, https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=10770

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue

```
pi@jarvis:~ $ hcitool dev
Devices:
```

with a **inactive** hciuart.service

```
pi@jarvis:~ $ systemctl status hciuart.service
● hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

After a

```
pi@jarvis:~ $ sudo systemctl start hciuart.service
```

I've got

```
pi@jarvis:~ $ systemctl status hciuart.service
● hciuart.service - Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hciuart.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-05-20 17:42:40 CEST; 2s ago
```

and

```
pi@jarvis:~ $ hcitool dev
Devices:
    hci0    B8:27:EB:E5:7C:B0
```

Answer (score 3):

Check your file /boot/config.txt for an entry like

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

and make sure this line is commented out by adding a # at the beginning of the line. If it is not commented out this line will disconnect the bluetooth from the UART and connect the UART with GPIO pins instead. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `BerryBoot`, and try `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Or you can reinstall the newest `raspbian` from official site.

Comment: How do you know the OP uses BerryBoot, and why shouldn't he use it?