# Raspberry Pi 3 Bluetooth "No default controller available"

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth, raspbian-jessie

I'm running Jessie, and an apt-get update/upgrade has no work to do. The kernel is at version `4.4.11-v7+ #891`. An `hcitool` scan says there's no device available. `bluetoothctl` says *No default controller available*.

I'm really, really, REALLY sure this is a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: I believe that the proper way to upgrade so as to have the bluetooth enabled is `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: I had done that. Bluetooth was working at one point after the upgrade (and several hours of hacking) and it stopped working sometime after that for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package `raspberrypi-sys-mods` was missing. Adding that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this related question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47045/hcitool-scan-says-no-such-device) I got it working by running:

```
sudo systemctl start hciuart.service
```