# Raspberry Pi 3 Bluetooth issue

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, driver

Similar to [Raspberry Pi 3 Bluetooth "No default controller available"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/48220/raspberry-pi-3-bluetooth-no-default-controller-available) however that fix doesn't work (already have that package installed)

Running latest Raspbian and have run rpi-update, apt-get update, upgrade and dist-upgrade (in all possible combinations). All the packages that setup guides are requiring are installed (bluez, pi-bluetooth, etc...)

```
~$ uname -r
4.4.21-v7+
~$ systemctl status bluetooth
...
Active: active (running)
...
~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
~$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

I have RetroPie installed over Raspbian with a piTFT from Adafruit. Not sure if the driver installer for the tft would cause any problems or not...

Is there some configuration/setup I am missing? My Pi is acting like the bluetooth hardware is nonexistent. And before anyone asks, yes this *IS* a RPi version 3 B, the builtin wireless works flawlessly and my CPU is reported as a22082 (3 Model B, Embest)
I am also a member of the bluetooth group
Update: firmware-brcm80211 is already installed.

Comment: Edit in the output from `uname -r`.

Comment: I had success on [minibian](https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/how-to/rpi3/) by running `apt-get install firmware-brcm80211 pi-bluetooth wpasupplicant`. 
since you already have installed `pi-bluetooth` can you try installing only the firmware ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I just checked and it's already installed

Comment: I just noticed that hciuart service fails during boot (calls hciattach on /dev/serial1) I will try to track the issue further and post my findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I had the line
`dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt`
In /boot/config.txt, which disables the bluetooth, additionally, my bluetoothd was not marked executable (is it supposed to be that way?) Which stopped its service from running.